# how to define event below

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function below where it doesn't allow the user to type in letters in a textbox but it keeps saying event is undefined. Where and how am I suppose to define event?

Below is the function:

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
```

Below is the html where this could be used:

```
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
```

to

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
```

or if you are using jQuery (you tagged it but aren't using it) you could do

```
$('#textareaid').keypress(function(e) {
     if (e.which > 31 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

where your html is

```
<textarea id="textareaid"></textarea>
```

See [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Note on how to get key pressed using jQuery

> To determine which character was entered, examine the event object
>   that is passed to the handler function. While browsers use differing
>   properties to store this information, jQuery normalizes the .which
>   property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code.

Taken from the [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) docs

Answer (score 0):

here is the code which should work:

```
function checkerFunction(e){
    var charCode=e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(charCode<=31 || charCode>=48 && charCode<=57)return true;
    return false;
}
```

and the event binding should be

```
onkeypress="return checkerFunction(window.event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record I think that most of the answers above don't take into consideration the ARROW keys.

This should be how it works incase you are googling this.

```
function isNumberKey(event)
{
   var charCode = event.charCode;
   if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 0){
       return false;
   }
    return true;
}
```